# Find word with Python "Regex"

Tags: python, regex

can you help please:
i want to get the adress from that text using python:

```
 [RIPH] harambe protocol

First alert listed in this telegram group 637 seconds before anyone else.

Coin name:    harambe protocol
Address:         0x10964C2ffDEA1e99B5e26D102516d9b03368915f
Platform:        BSC
Time:               08:02:58 UTC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

with open('textfile') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search(r'Address:\s*(0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+)', line)
        if (m):
            print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
0x10964C2ffDEA1e99B5e26D102516d9b03368915f
```

Comment: it's not a text file

Comment: It just represents the filename. Change the filename to whatever you have.

Comment: i used that code and returned nothing:

Comment: m = re.search("Address:\s*(0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+)", text)
 if m:
  print(m.group(1))

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import re

pattern = "Address:.*(0x.*)"

address = re.findall(pattern, your_text, re.MULTILINE)

print(address)
```

Comment: and how to print only the adress?

Comment: This regex only takes the address: 
address = re.findall(pattern, your_text, re.MULTILINE);
print(address)

Comment: it return ' [] '

Comment: Change the pattern to this:     pattern = "Address:(.*)"

Comment: i got    [' **                '0xi0964C2fEDEfte99B5e26D102516d9b033689151"]

Comment: i want only from 0x to 151

Comment: The data you sent in the question is different from what you are saying now. I updated the pattern, if your address always starts with 0x you can use this pattern. Other views You can update the question with the correct data.